# SQL Server 2012 - Finding out which transaction logs have been applied to a NORECOVER db

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a copy of an offsite production database used for reporting which is running on SQL Server 2012. I want to start updating it hourly with transaction logs from that offsite production database.

No big deal, restore a full backup (w/ `NORECOVERY`) to get things started and apply the transaction logs (w/ `NORECOVERY`) as they come in.

However, in the event of a problem with the restore (or with getting the log files) I could end up with several transaction log files, some of which have been applied and others that have not.  When that happens, how do I figure out which file to start with in my TSQL script?

I tried looking in the restore history table like this:

```
select distinct 
    h.destination_database_name, 
    h.restore_date, 
    s.server_name, 
    m.physical_device_name as backup_device, 
    f.physical_name 
from
    msdb..restorehistory h
inner join 
    msdb..backupfile f on h.backup_set_id = f.backup_set_id 
inner join 
    msdb..backupset s on f.backup_set_id = s.backup_set_id
inner join 
    msdb..backupmediafamily m on s.media_set_id = m.media_set_id
where 
    h.destination_database_name = 'mydb'
    and h.restore_date > (GETDATE() -0.5)
order by 
    h.restore_date
```

But checking restorehistory is no good because the NORECOVERY flag means no records have been added in that table. So is there another way to check this, via T-SQL, that works for a NORECOVERY database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a rare manual operation, the simplest way to is scan the errorlog.

SQL Server's built-in log shipping (and some third party implementations) have tables, views and user interfaces that make this simpler.

Comment: No, it's not a manual process.  I'm thinking ahead to the automated job's error handling.  If something goes wrong, I'd like it to try picking up where it left off and minimize my intervention for minor hiccups.  Also, I'm not using any 3rd party log shipping.

Comment: Then you will need to create your own tracking table somewhere. May I ask why not use SQL Server's built in log shipping?

Comment: My understanding of SQL Server's log shipping is that it's for moving logs from your primary to your secondary server(s).  In this case, I don't have control over the primary server.  It's an offsite db under a 3rd party's control.  They put the logs up for SFTP and, currently, we go get them and use them in our nightly restore.  I'm looking to get rid of the nightly full restore and move us to a standby db where logs are applied as they come in.  I was hoping to get around building a table to track it (which was my first impulse) but it's looking like I'll have to.